# Add and get the sum off floats from entry in label

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

I got a bit of a noob question.

I want  to add the floats from the 3 entries, so the total float is shown in the label.

My solution is this and I can't get it to work, what I'm doing wrong?

Thx in advance..

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.var = DoubleVar()
        self.var.set(float(0.00))
        self.var2 = DoubleVar()
        self.var2.set(float(0.00))
        self.var3 = DoubleVar()
        self.var3.set(float(0.00))

        self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var3)
        self.entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)


        self.total = DoubleVar()
        self.total.set(float(0.00))

        self.totalSum = Label(root, textvariable=self.total, relief='sunken')
        self.totalSum.grid(row=5, column=1)


    def totalSum(self):
        self.total.set(self.var.get() + self.var2.get() + self.var3.get())



root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.title("help")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a method called `.totalSum`, but you shadow that with a Label called `.totalSum`.

Comment: Your `totalSum` method is never called. If I understand correctly, you want the sum to update automatically every time one of the 3 numbers changes?

Comment: Arh I can see that @Aran-Fey And your right, thats exactly what I want.I tried to change my function name to sumTotal, but dosent work.

Answer (score 0):

The `totalSum` method is never called.

Ive created a button that calls the method and calculates the sum.

Also, ive changed the method name since you already have a label called `totalSum`.

And the method `calculateTotalSum` needs to be called inside the `__init__` method.

Here's the working code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.var = DoubleVar()
        self.var.set(float(0.00))
        self.var2 = DoubleVar()
        self.var2.set(float(0.00))
        self.var3 = DoubleVar()
        self.var3.set(float(0.00))

        self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var3)
        self.entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)


        self.total = DoubleVar()
        self.total.set(float(0.00))

        self.totalSum = Label(root, textvariable=self.total, relief='sunken')
        self.totalSum.grid(row=5, column=1)

        def calculateTotalSum():
            self.total.set(self.var.get() + self.var2.get() + self.var3.get())

        self.button = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculateTotalSum)
        self.button.grid(row=6, column=1)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.title("help")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isent it possible to get it to update automatic? Without a button.

Comment: @Math There is no event that happens when the values of an EntryBox value is changed. If there was it could be possible to call the method, but it isn't possible as it require's an event.

Comment: @Math Sort of. You can bind Event handlers to each Entry that call the summing method whenever a key or mousebutton is pressed. Eg, using your original method name, `self.entry1.bind("<Key>", self.totalSum);  self.entry1.bind("<Button>", self.totalSum)` Etc.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes but that still wouldn't be automatic and requires a key press.

Comment: How can you change the value of an Entry without using a key press or a mousebutton press?

Comment: Why do you say "the method `calculateTotalSum` needs to be called inside the `__init__` method"? You _can_ define a callback function inside `__init__`  like your version does, but it's also possible to use a method like the OP's `totalSum` as the callback. Of course, it needs to have the appropriate argument signature.

Comment: @PM2Ring I tried but it didn't work.